# how does getline() read a multiple-line file in loops?

Tags: c++, function, iostream, ifstream, getline

I have some confusion about the use of std::getline function. see the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
std::ifstream ifs(filename);
std::string line;

while (std::getline(ifs, line))
{
  //...//
}

for ( std::string s; getline(ifs, s)){
  //...//
}
```

For both of the while loop and the for loop, it seems like each time in a new iteration, the "geline" is reading a new line, e.g. if we have a file storing:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

then in the first iteration, getline reads `1 2` , then `3 4` in the next iteration... so, how does it know from which line it should start reading when an iteration starts?

Comment: it reads from the current position of the stream?

Comment: It's because it reads from a [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145357/what-is-a-stream-in-c). The stream (`ifs` in this case) is passed by reference, so it's always referring to the same object which gets updated.

Comment: the `ifstream` has an index internally to remember where it is in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file stream is a source of bytes (“characters”). Each time you read a character from the file the *file get pointer* is advanced to the next character to read.

That is, each time you read, you get the next *unread* character.

`std::getline()` simply reads characters until it gets the delimiter value (which is `'\n'` by default). Hence each call to getline() gets the next line in the file.